# How do I convert the bits in a ulong into a double?

Tags: c#, double, ieee-754, bit

I'm looking for a C# equivalent to Java's [Double.longBitsToDouble](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) method. I have a double value stored in a ulong and I want those bits to be converted to represent a double. Is there an easy way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Answer (score -1):

you may want to look it

```
  BitConverter.ToDouble()
```

Comment: Seems to be BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble